# Mysql alter/write lock database

Tags: mysql-5.6

I runned this in mysql:

```
UPDATE db SET Insert_priv='Y', Create_priv='Y' WHERE Db='wordpress_fixed';
```

But this not preventing from inserting more data to database wordpress_fixed. Is it supposed to work that way?

Comment: Direct granting privilege (setting it to `'Y'`) kills preventing for according action (after flushing, of course). If you want to revoke some privilege directly you must set according parameter to `'N'` value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually update any mysql.X table regarding privileges will require a [FLUSH PRIVILEGES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html) to effect the change.

Using [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) is the better way of of ensuring privs exists (and doesn't require `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`).